# Database column in a while loop isn't getting changed

Tags: python, database, while-loop, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am changing a value inside my database on my website. I am sure it is getting changed. I am printing the value

```
computer.directory_response = "example" # not the actual value it's always changing
            db.session.commit()
            print(computer.directory_response)
```

I can see the printed value in the console. meanwhile, I have a program that sends a request to `/computers/1/ajax-dir`. the problem in the code is when I am doing a while loop to check if the value is `example` (to be sure I just implemented the if statement inside the while loop)

```
while(computer.directory_response == ""):
                if computer.directory_response != "":
                    break
                else:
                    pass
```

at the beginning it's empty. Yes. But even when I change the value in the first part of code I showed you it's still in the while loop. I don't understand why it doesn't change I am using flask as a backend language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you aren't adding the `computer` to the `db.session`.

As that's the case you should add this before the `db.commit()`:

```
db.session.add(computer)
```

Comment: I have multiple `db.commit` should I just put it at the start of the path? or before every `db.commit()` note: I am not trying to create a new row just update a value

Comment: Yes before every db.session.commit().

Comment: You are right it worked. Can you explain why? because for some commits I don't use it and it still works

Comment: I would suggest you to check out the link. Also if it helped you please mark my answer as accepted

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work I just tested it again it probably worked because I didn't delete the data from the database

Comment: Can you print the value of computer.directory_response just before the while loop

Comment: It's an empty string (as it should be)

Comment: How do you create the computer object

Comment: Yeah this is the first command I do in the root `computer = Todo.query.get_or_404(id)` (Todo is the table name for the `computer.directory_response`)

Comment: Also you should call `.first()` on the query

Comment: It's fine, not crucial it's not going to fix the bug. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: It definitely exists though I can see the URL (getting the id from the URL) and it is the right URL for sure it's not that besides it does print data in the function

Comment: I don't know but why is the while loop used

Comment: It's to check if the value changes in a different root. if it changes then you can exit the while loop

Comment: So the while loop isn't in a route

Comment: Yeah it's in a different one why does that matter I still update the DB
the while loop and the commit are in different routes

Comment: But wouldn't it time out

Comment: No, I tried printing the value in the `while` loop and it continues on printing also when the value changed

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem anymore really at all